# Further Lomdus/Research on Horayos

Tags: product-recommendation, brisk, masechet-horayot

Does anyone recommend brisker-style seforim specific to Horayos or Eduyos? Additionally, are there and modern research style discussions on judicial error in Horayos available?

Comment: Probably useful https://hebrewbooks.org/9469

Answer (score 6):

R. Avraham Kaplan, [Birkas Avraham on Horiyos](https://hebrewbooks.org/53649); R. Moshe Rosmarin, Devar Moshe on Horiyos; R. Avraham Genechovsky, Cheder Horasi; R. Efraim Garboz, [Har Efraim](https://hebrewbooks.org/30727); R. Binyamin Yuzhuk, Yosher Horai/Imrei Binyamin; a good resource is [Avodah Berurah](https://hebrewbooks.org/50949) on Horiyos.

Comment: Any idea where to find Har Efraim? Virtually impossible to find in the US.

Comment: There is a link to hebrewbooks.org in the answer: https://hebrewbooks.org/30727

Answer (score 3):

[R. Aharon Lichtenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Lichtenstein)'s students published notes of his *shiurim* on Horayot.

They are available for free in [the VBM](https://www.etzion.org.il/he/%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA) or for purchase as [a *sefer*](https://www.alonshvut-archive.org.il/objDoc.asp?PID=941415&OID=965647&DivID=5).